# Set value of dynamic text field inside a button object

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I've got a dynamic text field in my button object. I have named the text field "myText". How can I modify the text within it? `myButton.myText.text = "test";` won't work, because it can't access `myText`.

Comment: Also, I've not done Flash coding in a couple years now, so I apologize for what's probably a very quick fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually just create a MovieClip that contains a blank button and a dynamic text field.
If you set `mouseEnabled = false` on the text field, it won't interfere with the mouse events on the button.

Edit:
Here's and example of a custom button class I use sometimes:

```
package {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.text.TextField

public class CustomButton extends MovieClip {

    public var t_label:TextField; 

    public function CustomButton() {
        t_label.mouseEnabled = false;
        mouseChildren = false;
        buttonMode = true;

        this.gotoAndStop("normal");
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, onMouseOver);
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, onMouseOut);
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onMouseDown);
    }

    public function setLabel(buttonLabel:String):void {
        t_label.text = buttonLabel;
    }

    public function destroy():void {
        removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, onMouseOver);
        removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, onMouseOut);
        removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onMouseDown);
    }

    protected function onMouseOver(e:MouseEvent):void {
        this.gotoAndStop("over");
    }

    protected function onMouseOut(e:MouseEvent):void {
        this.gotoAndStop("normal");
    }

    protected function onMouseDown(e:MouseEvent):void {
        this.gotoAndPlay("down");
    }

}
```

}

You can link this to a MovieClip that has frames labeled "normal", "over" and "down" and it will function like a normal button with a dynamic label.

If you need to customize the text appearance for the different states you can do so within the event handlers.

Comment: How will the text field know to change colors then when the button state has changed? It's white text on black button in the upState, and the inverse on the downState.

Comment: It won't. If you need to change the text appearance for the button states you'd have to use another method. You could create a custom class that handles MOUSE_OVER, MOUSE_OUT, and MOUSE_DOWN events and adjusts the text color accordingly.

Comment: Is there any way to handle a button state change instead of the mouse movements?

Comment: I updated my answer to show the method I usually use for this. But you might prefer to do what shanethehat suggests and assign the button states to different graphics. Then you don't have to mess with the mouse events (except CLICK, presumably).

Answer (score 0):

**Updated answer:**

I have two solutions for you, but one requires that you only have a single TextField in the button and no other objects.

**1:**

If you have only a single TextField in your button then the `upState` property of your button will be a TextField, and you can then directly set its text property:

```
myButton.upState.text = "Click Me";
myButton.downState.text = "Click Me";
myButton.overState.text = "Click Me";
```

**2:**

If the first technique doesn't apply to you the solution is a bit more complicated.

First, create a MovieClip in your library containing the current contents of the up frame of your button. Set it to export and give it a class name (`TextHolder`).  Then you can create a TextHolder object, set its textLabel's text property, and assign it to each button state:

```
var buttonState:TextHolder = new TextHolder();
buttonState.myText.text = "Click me";
myButton.upState = myButton.downState = myButton.overState = myButton.hitTestState = buttonState;
```

If you want to create different states, say with differently colored text, you would have to create different objects for the different states:

```
var buttonState:TextHolder = new TextHolder();
var buttonStateOver:TextHolder = new TextHolder();
buttonState.myText.text =  buttonStateOver.myText.text = "Hello";
buttonStateOver.x = 10;
myButton.upState = buttonState;
myButton.hitTestState = buttonState;
myButton.downState = myButton.overState = buttonStateOver;
```

Comment: That's unfortunate. Thank you!

Comment: Unmarked as correct because I may have actually found something which works without doing all that. I will mark again if I cannot get it to work. `myButton.upState` seems promising...

Comment: Thanks! I'm still having troubles, but I'm heading in the right direction.

Comment: Will your option 2 work if it's got other (non-named) objects? My current button looks like: http://i.imgur.com/gD7me.png

Comment: You would have to add those other elements to the TextHolder component. I'll update my answer for clarity.

Comment: And what about it being an actual button still? It isn't changing state, nor is it firing the click event.

Comment: I've edited my answer again to allow for that. You also have to assign an object to the `hitTestState` property.

Comment: It's just flashing like crazy now, but the click is registering again.

Comment: I figured out that it seems to be toggling the state 2-3 times each time I mouse on or off, leaving it in various visible states.